# Pandas Crosstab with third column

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

I have a Dataframe `df` that looks like this, although I have 20+ `P(n)` columns;

```
Time    Speed    P1     P2    Ratio
1       100      2      NaN     1.2
2       150      3      NaN     1.3
3       500      4      NaN     1.4
4       500      5      NaN     1.5
5       900      NaN      7     1.6
6       150      NaN      6     1.7
7       100      NaN      8     1.8
```

I'm trying to crosstabulate this data to build a new Dataframe, with the `Ratio` value for every value of `Speed` and `P(n)`. So that the result would look something like this;

```
Time    Speed    P1       P2    
1       100      1.2      NaN
2       150      1.3      NaN
3       500      1.4      NaN
4       500      1.5      NaN
5       900      NaN      1.6
6       150      NaN      1.7
7       100      NaN      1.8
```

Essentially, my aim is to replace the values for `P(n)` with the values for `Ratio`.

It seems like a simple task, however I'm quite stuck here. I have tried to use pandas crosstab but can only seem to utilise two variables to return the number of instances rather than the values. I tried this;

```
new_df = pd.crosstab(df['Speed'], df['Ratio'].fillna('n/a'))
```

Is it possible to use `pd.crosstab` to achieve this or is another method available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for get DataFrame with columsn starting by `P` and then for replace use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) for not missing values tested by [`DataFrame.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html):

```
df1 = df.filter(regex='^P')
df[df1.columns] = df1.mask(df1.notna(), df['Ratio'], axis=0)

print (df)
   Time  Speed   P1   P2  Ratio
0     1    100  1.2  NaN    1.2
1     2    150  1.3  NaN    1.3
2     3    500  1.4  NaN    1.4
3     4    500  1.5  NaN    1.5
4     5    900  NaN  1.6    1.6
5     6    150  NaN  1.7    1.7
6     7    100  NaN  1.8    1.8
```